# The best way to refer to the difference between two numbers

Tags: single-word-requests

Let's say I have a goal of working 100 hours but I've only worked 80.

Or I planned on working 100 but ended up working 120.

How do I refer to the 20? *I need a word that would imply that these hours need to be made up, completed.*

I tend to think **Gap** is the best word, but I'm not convinced.

The word **difference**, in my opinion, doesn't fit well in the context. Because I feel that it suggests simply a mathematic consequence, but not an independently existing item.

> Example (as table columns):
>
> 1. Total Hours Worked: 80
> 2. Total Required Hours: 100
> 3. _________: 20

Comment: Gap would apply to working less but not more.  Nothing wrong with *difference*.   Look, how do you produce this difference without using subtraction to find the...difference?  You could use "Hours Over/Under" if you prefer, and you could simplify to Hours Worked and Hours Required, which gives you parallelism.

Comment: **Net** might be an option too.

Comment: The **extra** hours?

Answer (score 1):

***discrepancy***:

> [Cambridge English Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/discrepancy):
>
>   an unexpected difference,
>     esp. in two amounts or two sets of facts or conditions,
>     which suggests that something is wrong and has to be explained:
>   *There were troubling discrepancies
>     between his public and private opinions on how to balance the budget.*
>
> [Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/discrepancy):
>
>   a difference between things that should be the same
>   *There were some discrepancies in the statement he gave to the police.*
>   *a discrepancy between estimated and actual spending*
>
> [English Oxford (living) Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/discrepancy):
>
>   An illogical or surprising lack of compatibility or similarity
>     between two or more facts.
>   *‘there’s a discrepancy between your account and his’*
>
> [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/discrepancy):
>
>   If there is a discrepancy between two things that ought to be the same,
>     there is a noticeable difference between them.
>
> [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/discrepancy):
>
> 1. the state or quality of being discrepant or in disagreement,
>      as by displaying an unexpected or unacceptable difference; inconsistency:
>      *The discrepancy between the evidence
>      and his account of what happened led to his arrest.*
>
>    an instance of difference or inconsistency:
>      *There are certain discrepancies between the two versions of the story.*

Answer (score 1):

***Remaining*** is defined by [Cambridge English Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/remaining):

> continuing to exist or be left after other parts or things have been used or taken away

Example:

> Total Hours Worked: 80
>
> Total Required Hours: 100
>
> Total Hours *Remaining*: 20

---

***Outstanding*** is defined by [Cambridge English Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/outstanding):

> not yet done, solved, or paid

Example:

> Total Hours Worked: 80
>
> Total Required Hours: 100
>
> Total Hours *Outstanding*: 20

---

***Due*** is defined by [Cambridge English Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/due):

> owed as a debt or as a right

Example:

> Total Hours Worked: 80
>
> Total Required Hours: 100
>
> Total Hours *Due*: 20

Comment: @DAE if you're happy with the answer, please select and up vote, if not please let us know, so we can edit our answers!

Answer (score 0):

How about **extra** hours?

[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/extra):

*adjective*:

- beyond or more than what is usual, expected, or necessary; additional

*noun*:

- something extra or additional